# Handling window in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While automating via Selenium WebDriver, I have the below scenario.

On a window I click on a button. Code will do the query to DB and display a window with its findings.
I am unable to switch to the new window.
The parent window is closed on clicking the button and I am not able to switch to the new window, since the control is on the parent window and it is not visible on the screen.

Can someone please help me with this.
Thanks

My code is as follow:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='WIN_0_560700305']/div/div")).click();
window1=driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(window1);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
windowList = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println("Number of Windows-->" + driver.getWindowHandles().size());
iterator = windowList.iterator();
String window2 = null;
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("Entering while loop");
    window2 = (String)iterator.next();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
if (!(window1.equals(window2))){
    driver.switchTo().window(window2);
    System.out.println("Title of the page after - switchingTo: " +
        driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Current url" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='WIN_0_540000016']/div/div")).click();
```

Comment: The child window is opened just after that the parent is closed or just before ?

Comment: a DB query is done, then the child window is opened. the parent window is hidden and the focus is still on the parent window. Not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit, try with the code below, Hope it will work.

```
String window1=driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='WIN_0_560700305']/div/div")).click();
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
Set windowList = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator iterator = windowList.iterator();
String window2 = null;
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("Entering while loop");
    window2 = iterator.next().toString();
    if(!(window1.equals(window2))){
       driver.switchTo().window(window2);
       System.out.println("Title of the page after - switchingTo: " +          
       driver.getTitle());
       System.out.println("Current url" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
//Switched to new window, do operations in new window    ..
```

Comment: this is the output. When the while loop is running all the window names are same. i mean focus is still on parent window. Please help.Number of Windows-->3
Dsp_ KIA_AssetSearch
Dsp_ KIA_AssetSearch
Dsp_ KIA_AssetSearch
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == .//*[@id='WIN_0_540000016']/div/div (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 315 milliseconds